# Saving Post hasMany Student habtm Subject in Cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm trying to save 3 tables of data from PostController and their relationships are as follow:

`Post hasMany Student`
`Student hasAndBelongsToMany Subject`

In `posts/` I have a multistep form, in the first step of which I have these inputs to save students:

```
$this->Form->input('Student.0.name');
$this->Form->input('Student.1.name'); //an additional field that maybe added by the user
```

In the last step, I count the number of students input by the user in step 1 and then output the inputs for subjects accordingly like this:

```
$this->Form->input('Subject.0.name'); //Subject(s) for student 1
$this->Form->input('Subject.1.name'); //Subject(s) for student 2
```

But I don't know how to set the field names in Cakephp to save the subjects for each students in `Post` model.

Comment: Why do you output only one `Subject` for student 1 while you have a HABTM relationship?

Comment: That's where I want to change :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
foreach ($this->session->data['Student'] as $key => $value) {
    $val = 'Student.' . $key . '.Subject';
    echo $this->Form->input($val);
}
```

The field names for `subject` inputs (submitting from `Post` model) should be: `Student.0.Subject`. And I output the inputs using foreach loop so it's ready for any number of fields added by the user, and each fields correspond to respective student.